# When to use "la vie de milliers" and when to use "les vies de milliers"?

Tags: grammaire, pluriel

> **La vie** de milliers de personnes est en jeu. (NOT: les vies)

{**The lives** of thousands of people are at stake.}

> Il connaissait **le nom** de toutes les plantes. (NOT: les noms)

{He knew **the names** of all the plants.}

---

The reason for having to use the singular form has me intrigued, as this is in stark contrast to how it works in English.

Comment: In both your sentences it is possible, and not grammatically wrong to use the plural (*les vies de*... & *les noms de toutes*... On the same line in French we'd say something like *Ils ont leur chapeau sur la tête* (as opposed "they're wearing their hats on their heads") because French considers each one of them has only got one head and you only wear one hat at a time. Different languages view and express certain things in different ways.

Comment: To @Laure: I was wondering if inserting the word "each" into the translations might help to explain the rationale for using the singular noun in French. {**The life of each of** the thousands of people **is** at stake.} & {He knew **the name of each of** the plants.} Merci.

Comment: Yes indeed in the case of your examples it's because French considers that each person has his/her own life that singular can be used, **alongside plural** (you seem to think it is not possible the way you wrote your question).  It's only in the case of a sentence like *Ils ont leur chapeau sur la tête* that plural would be used in French, so I think your question is more about why is plural possible in one instance and not in the other?

Comment: À : @Laure Exactement. Dans des phrases comme celles-ci, je constate que le nom placé devant « de » est tantôt au singulier, tantôt au pluriel, alor que les phrases anglaises correspondantes ont toujours un nom pluriel. Quand il faut utiliser le singulier et quand il me faut le pluriel... je ne pouvais pas les distinguer l'un de l'autre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> La vie de milliers de personnes est en jeu.
>   Il connaissait le nom de toutes les plantes.
>
> Les vies de milliers de personnes sont en jeu.
>   Il connaissait les noms de toutes les plantes.

Dans ce genre de construction l'emploi du singulier ou du pluriel est possible et il n'y a pas de prescription grammaticale pour ou contre l'un des deux. Il n'est pas sûr que ceux qui emploient l'un ou l'autre fassent un choix toujours conscient. Cependant on pourrait voir une différence de point de vue entre les deux formes, je donne ici ce qui est une interprétation personnelle.

> La vie de milliers de personnes est en jeu.

En individualisant la vie de chacun on souligne l'importance de cette vie, ce qui est mis en valeur c'est le rapport entre la vie et l'individu (ou le lien entre chaque plante et son nom).

> Les vies de milliers de personnes sont en jeu.

Le choix du pluriel met l'accent sur la quantité, ce qui est mis en valeur c'est le grand nombre de vie mis en jeu, on insiste plus sur la menace qui pèse sur ces vies (on admire la grande mémoire de celui qui mémorise tous ces noms de plantes).

---

Il ne faut pas confondre avec une autre construction ou effectivement le français impose le choix du singulier.

> Les garçons ont leur casquette sur la tête.

Dans cette phrase la langue française considère que chaque personne a une seule tête et que chaque tête a une seule casquette. Écrire en français que les garçons ont « leurs casquettes sur leurs têtes » reviendrait en français à signifier que chaque garçon a plusieurs têtes (à l'oral bien sûr on n'entend pas ici les marques de pluriel). Écrire  que les garçons ont « leur casquette sur leurs têtes » impliquerait qu'il y a une seule et même casquette qui couvre toutes les têtes. Écrire que les garçons ont « leurs casquettes sur la tête » signifierait que chaque garçon a plusieurs casquettes sur sa tête.

Il faut constater qu'ici, comme c'est souvent le cas quand on fait de la linguistique comparative, le lien intime qui existe entre notre perception du monde et la langue que nous parlons.
L'italien (*I ragazzi hanno il cappello in testa*) et l'espagnol (*los jóvenes llevan la gorra en la cabeza*) adopte le même point de vue que le français alors que l'anglais exprime la pluralité des têtes et des couvre-chefs (*the boys have got their caps on their heads*) et que l'allemand admet aussi bien le singulier que le pluriel pour les casquettes mais considère dans tous les cas que la tête est au singulier (*Die Jungs haben die Mütze auf dem Kopf* / *Die Jungs haben die Mützen auf dem Kopf*)

Cette remarque me fait penser à [un article](https://theconversation.com/how-the-language-you-speak-changes-your-view-of-the-world-40721) d'un linguiste britannique qui, à travers d'exemples pris en anglais et en allemand (expériences menées sur des sujets bilingues), montrait comment la structure de la langue que nous utilisons influence notre perception du monde.

Comment: To: @Laure: I find the "casquette" comparison enlightening and interesting. This is exactly what I was hoping to find out. Merci.

Comment: To: @Laure: I was under the impression that up/down votes are only for native speakers to use to objectively judge the quality and accuracy of the answers posted. For this very reason, I have refrained from using them so far. Then, I'll start casting them from now on! Merci.

Comment: @LUNA  Thanks. You can up- or down -vote any questions or answers to show how you feel about it. You don't **have to** it's just a possibility and how the Stack Exchange sites work.

Answer (score 2):

Both singular and plural are grammatically possible in French with your example, so you have the choice depending on the logic.

If there is one live or one name for each, then you use singular, otherwise you can use the plural. Using "each" doesn't help to decide if it is singular or plural, though :

> Il serra la main de tous ses invités. (you usually shake the right hand, it would be special to shake both hands at the same time)
>
> Il connaissait les faiblesses de chaque adversaire. (Each opponent had a few weaknesses, if you use "la faiblesse" here then it would sound like all opponents are weaks)
>
> Il respectait les coutumes de tous les pays qu'il visitait.